# [Twitter Streaming API]Is it possible to track keyword from the user's timeline?

Tags: java, android, json, twitter-streaming-api

I have a code that could receive the PUBLIC API and filter by keywords, but now I want this filtering function only provide tweets from my home timeline.

I read the official materials about streaming api, it seems that these two things can be done separately, just not together because the parameters that "filter.json", "user.json" and others support are different, like "track" wouldn't work with "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json" or "https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json", and there is no "with=follows" parameter in "filter.json".

Is there anyway I could make it track keywords from user's timeline? An example code would be awesome, or just tips that could put me in the right direction are much appreciated too.

Comment: What's exactly the problem of using the timeline? You won't receive so many tweets and you can filter them afterwards. Anyway, if you want a streaming endpoint with filtering, take a look to [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter). Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I can get either the user's home timeline without being able to filter, or I can get the public API(all the tweets from all users) and I can filter them by certain keywords, but not the both things together. And I read though the official sites, doesn't seem to have a way to do both.

Comment: Ok, I understand. However I meant that the timeline is not so big. You could download it completely and then filter keywords over the results.